# Constant to Dimension

Tags: xparse

Say I define a constant like:

```
\fp_const:Nn \c_shcphi_fp   { 1.618 0339 8874 9894 }
```

And now I want use it globally for creating dimensions, say, for the width of a box. How can I create a command that does this automatically?

Here is a MWE am working on:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\fp_const:Nn \c_shcphi_fp   { 1.618 0339 8874 9894 } % phi (golden ratio) constant

\NewDocumentCommand{\shcevalphi}{  O{5} }
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round (\c_shcphi_fp , #1) }
 } 

\ExplSyntaxOff 


\begin{document}
    \shcevalphi[3]
\end{document}
```

Note that the command above can use the the new constant I created.

I want to also be able to define operations with it like a new length being

```
2 * \c_shcphi_fp - 1 %random example of length computation.
```

Comment: `\dim_const:Nn \c_shcphi_dim { 1.618 0339 8874 9894 pt }` and use `\dim_eval:N`?

Comment: `\fp_eval:n { 2 * \c_shcphi_fp - 1 }` would evaluate your expression, but note that this would calculate a float, not a length.

Comment: There is currently no interface for adding named functions or constants; however, nothing stops you from saying `\fp_const:Nn \shcphi {1.6...}` and use something like `\setlength{\mylen}{\fpeval(2\shcphi-1)pt}` (needs `\usepackage{xfp}`).

Comment: @HenriMenke can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @egreg can you post your comment as an answer? I also noticed `\c_shcphi_fp` is defined in a similar manner `\fp_const:Nn \c_pi_fp { 3.141 5926 5358 9793 }`. Can you cite some areas where this is used in your answer and the reason why it is defined that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The floating point module of `expl3` has currently no interface for adding named constants or functions.

You could do

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\fp_const:Nn \c_shcphi_fp   { 1.618 0339 8874 9894 } % phi (golden ratio) constant
\fp_set_eq:NN \shcphi \c_shcphi_fp % for "external" use

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlength{\azetinalen}
\setlength{\azetinalen}{\fpeval{2\shcphi-1}pt}
```

or whatever expression you need. Since `\fpeval` is fully expandable, it can be used essentially anywhere. Say you want to set your length equal to the textwidth multiplied by the golden ratio; then

```
\setlength{\azetinalen}{\fpeval{\shcphi}\textwidth}
```

will work.

There is no special reason why the definition for the constant `pi` is formatted as

```
\fp_const:Nn \c_pi_fp { 3.141 5926 5358 9793 }
```

It's just a convenient way to ensure that fifteen decimal digits are used. Remember that in the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn` spaces are ignored.

The constant is then internally used also for making `pi` a “legal” word in floating point expressions. I'm not sure that an interface for creating user defined words will ever be provided. On the other hand, I see no reason for not adding other common use constants, should the need arise. The golden ratio could be a candidate. On the other hand, you could also define it implicitly: with

```
\fp_const:Nn \c_goldenratio_fp { (1+sqrt(5)}/2 }
```

the assigned value would be `1.618 0339 8874 9895`, which is actually more accurate than the value you have (the sixteenth decimal digit is `8`).